# Is ajax content gzipped if the file is gzipped by server

Tags: javascript, ajax, gzip

I am just wondering if when gzip is activated at the server, will ajax calls be gzipped too? I don't know how to test it.

Comment: unless you tell the request not to accept gzip it does so automatically and i think that is all it does is tell the server wither or not to accept, i dont think it can actually control if the content is sent in gzip or not unless the server is coded to check if the request sent an accpets gzip header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Chrome or Firebug you can check the request and see the headers.

If you see something like `Content-Encoding: gzip` you're good :)

Answer (score 1):

That may depend a lot on how the server is configured, because one can select to compress certain mime types and not others, and in many cases there's also a minimum size under which content isn't compressed at all.

A tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) shows you all details of the traffic between a server and a browser, including whether content was gzipped or not.